# What's the source for the Challah lasting all week in Sarah's tent?

Tags: sources-mekorot, bread, parashat-chaye-sara, imahot-matriarch-mothers, myths

One of the three miracles that took place in Sarah's tent, (which returned when Rivka married Yitzchak) was that the candles burned for the whole week, the challah stayed fresh from week to week, and there was a cloud over the tent.

Rashi ([Bereishit 24:67](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219#showrashi=true&v=67)) does say regarding the Challah miracle 'a bracha was found in the dough.' ברכה מצויה בעיסה. but does not say what the miracle was, it could be anything, in fact some say that the miracle was that the dough increased miraculously, (Sapirstein chumash.)

Does anyone know the source for the Challah lasting all week in Sarah's tent?

seen here:
http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=32796&alias=please-debunk-this-parsha-myth

Comment: From the Medrash Rabba that Rashi was quoting and mifarshim on it, it seems the bracha was the ability to be mafrish bitahara. Thisis interesting being that the one time the Torah discusses Sarah making challa she actually became Nida! Obviously that was the exception but it is still interesting.

Comment: @MonicaCellio is that better?

Comment: What's extra ironic is getting the same exact source here as was given there:)

Comment: @EHS much better, thanks!  I'm going to clean up these comments now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the interpretation of the [Shem Mishmuel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Bornsztain_(second_Sochatchover_rebbe)) on the Parsha (5671). His reasoning is that the three 'blessings' of Sarah's tent correspond to three miracles that occurred in the Mishkan, the third of which was that the showbread remained fresh for the entire week. Therefore, he says that the 'blessing in the dough' means the same thing.

Comment: I get that the candle corresponded to the miracle of the Menorah (or at least the Ner Maaravi) staying lit, but what did the cloud correspond to? The pillar of smoke that rose from the Altar?

Comment: @Menachem Maybe the cloud pillar that led the way?

Comment: @Menachem http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9937/jewish/Chapter-9.htm#v=15

Comment: I just saw the original hebrew in the link @shmuelbrin posted http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48448/whats-the-source-for-the-challah-lasting-all-week-in-sarahs-tent/48450?noredirect=1#comment128188_48448, and it says explicitly the cloud that rested on the Mishkan.

Comment: you can read the text of the Shem MiShumuel on page 3 of this pdf: http://upload.kipa.co.il/media-upload/temple/1182012373246574.pdf